# multiple DNS for one domain

Tags: dns

Can I apply multiple DNS service for a single domain? I have DNS service provided by ClouDNS, he.net and Namecheap, can I set the NS record of one of my domains point to all these servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just need to make sure all these servers have same zone definition for your domain.
check the Name Servers of amazon.com
they are using dynect.net and ultradns